# ¿Porque al poner el menu fijo me come parte del contenido?

Tags: html5, css3

tengo un inconveniente con respecto al menú y el contenido, ya que al poner el menú fijo y darle clic en "nosotros" me come parte del contenido, mi menú es scroll.
Dejo adjunto el link de los archivos.

Es la primera vez que publico, así que pido disculpa si publico algo fuera de lugar, espero su ayuda, muchas gracias KacosPro por la data.

Saludos.

```css
/* Reseteo */

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}

body {
 line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}

table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}

body {
 -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

/* Navbar */
.container-navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: fixed;
}
.logo{
    width: 30%;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: firebrick;
}
.logo p a{
    color: black;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.menu{
    width: 70%;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu ul li{
    display: inline;
}
.menu ul li a{
    color: black;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 15px;
}
.menu ul li a:hover{
    color: white;
}

/* Secciones */
.slider-1{
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}
.slider-2{
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
}
.slider-3{
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}
.slider-4{
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
}

/* Footer */
.container-footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 24px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <title>Crenein</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="files/css/main.css">
    
    <!-- Scroll -->
    <script src="files/js/smooth-scroll.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      smoothScroll.init({
      selector: '[data-scroll]',
      selectorHeader: null,
      speed: 1000,
      easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
      offset: 0,
      callback: function ( anchor, toggle ) {}
      });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- logo -->
    <nav class="container-navbar">
        <div class="logo">
            <p><a href="www.crenein.com">Crenein</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- menu -->
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a data-scroll href="#sec-1">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a data-scroll href="#sec-2">Nosotros</a></li>
                <li><a data-scroll href="#sec-3">Servicios</a></li>
                <li><a data-scroll href="#sec-4">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Secciones -->
    <div class="container-sec">
        <div class="slider-1" id="sec-1">
            <p>Soporte ISP <br>
            Creciemiento - Negocio - Internet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-2" id="sec-2">
            <h1>NOSOTROS</h1>
            <p>Crenein es una empresa creada con el fin de ofrecer soluciones de networking escalables y rentables para ISPs. 
            Construimos redes de datos, pero también construimos redes de personas, fomentando el trabajo colaborativo. Creemos que el cooperativismo es la clave del éxito en un mundo donde la forma de hacer negocios se está transformando.
            Creemos en la retroalimentación del negocio, es decir; si nuestros clientes crecen nosotros crecemos.
            Trabajamos incansablemente en el desarrollo innovador de tecnologías y procesos que mejoran la operatividad del ISP.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-3" id="sec-3">
            <h1>SECCION 3</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="slider-4" id="sec-4">
            <h1>SECCION 4</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="container-footer">
        <p>Desarrollado por <a href="#">Manuel Alejandro Parcellier</a></p>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Script -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha384-3ceskX3iaEnIogmQchP8opvBy3Mi7Ce34nWjpBIwVTHfGYWQS9jwHDVRnpKKHJg7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-XTs3FgkjiBgo8qjEjBk0tGmf3wPrWtA6coPfQDfFEY8AnYJwjalXCiosYRBIBZX8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sería mejor que incluyeras tu código directamente en la pregunta y no un link de descarga. No sabemos si es malware, probablemente nadie lo descargue

Comment: Si tu código se puede ejecutar en el navegador puedes utilizar un [StackSnippet](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3292/qu%c3%a9-es-stack-snippet). Si no, puedes incluirlo directamente con el botón `{  }` o seleccionando el código completamente y presionando `Ctrl + k`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se "come el contenido" porque al ser fijo está por sobre el contenido.
agregarle un margen superior al contenido del mismo alto que el menú.
no se nota a la primera porque la primer sección está vacía (aunque se come el título).

```
.container-sec {margin-top:70px;}
```

Edit: faltaria fijar al top el menu para evitar comportamientos indeseados al hacer scroll

```
/* Navbar */
.container-navbar{
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: aqua;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

esto fijaria el navbar al top de la pagina y le da un margen al contenido para que se muestre por debajo

edit2: le ponemos el alto del menu al offset del scroll para que llegue bien

```
<script>
  smoothScroll.init({
  selector: '[data-scroll]',
  selectorHeader: null,
  speed: 1000,
  easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
  offset: -70px,
  callback: function ( anchor, toggle ) {}
  });
</script>
```

Comment: (https://ibb.co/ncTvsH) me quedo de esa manera al poner ese código, no debo dividir en el html para que se dividan el menú con el contenido?

Comment: ahi te modifique el ejemplo, al ponerle `top:0;` al menu le dices al navegador respecto a que queda fijo, como no lo tenia al hacer scroll se movia del margen.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahi quedo. Saludos.

Comment: ahi le edite nuevamente para marcar donde le decis al plugin de cuantos pixels debe pasarse para que quede justo